# How to reduce the amount of integration datasets used in Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am relatively new to this so would like some help, please.

So I have the following pipeline.

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbfpB.png)

It runs each element from a list of variables that I supplied, to an API, calls the data, stores the data and then appends it in a certain file format in a specific location.

I used 4 integration datasets for this while 3 of them being unique for this pipeline.

The first integration dataset (which I reuse) is the source where I attach each element from the list to API URL.

The second integration dataset is where I sink each file from the API to the storage location.

After the For Each block is ran, in the copy activity block, I use a third integration dataset to source all the data from that store using a wildcard to select all the data in that file. I then sink all that data with a fourth integration dataset, merging them all together and save it as a certain file format.

The problem I am having is that I have around 18 pipelines, if you multiply this by 3 unique integration datasets for each pipeline 54 integration datasets which Azure does not represent friendly manner to my knowledge.

Is there anyway I can reduce the amount of integration datasets used?

Comment: All pipelines are same? I mean, all uses same pipeline structure, same type of datasets?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula I might be making them inefficiently. Each pipeline basically does the same function but stores the file in different places. Like this https://imgur.com/a/wQjPdmV

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with a **Single dataset by making use of dataset parameters for container, folder path and file name**.

Give the dataset parameters like below.

[image]

Give your container name, folder path and file name for the copy activity inside ForEach.

[image]

Here, I have built the file name using the for each `@item()`.

Outside the ForEach, For the source of the copy activity, give **your container name only and fill the remaining parameters with empty strings(`''`)** like below.

Select Wildcard file path and give your folder path and wild card file path in it.

[image]

And in the sink of it, give your target container, folder path and file name and select **Merge files**.

[image]

For every pipeline, you need to do the same as per your folder structure.

This approach will reduce your dataset count from 4 to 2 for every pipeline.

You can use the same dataset for every pipeline if your folder structure and pipeline flow is same, but need to be careful while giving the values for those in every pipeline.

**My Result:**

[image]

Comment: What default parameters did you put for your dataset parameters

Comment: I didn't provided any default values.

Comment: Provided the respective values for them at the pipeline level in the activity itself like above.

Comment: Do I have to create folders separately for this or will this method make the folders required?

Comment: It will create the target folders. The first copy activity inside ForEach will create the respective folders(temporary folders) for the pipelines and second copy activity after ForEach gets the files from it and creates the target folder automatically.

Comment: But you need to pass the names of the folders and containers manually for every pipeline as every pipeline copy to different folders.

Comment: I think that is fine passing through manually. I do get a problem with my second copy activity "ErrorCode=UserErrorFileNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'." 

I passed in a container name in the sink and a folder that I created manually.

Comment: 'FileSystem: 'apidata'. ErrorCode: 'FilesystemNotFound'. Message: 'The specified filesystem does not exist.' This is a further error i got. Is temp container something I have to make beforehand?

Comment: In the second copy activity source, don't give the folder and file name as `double quote(")`, give an empty string which means two single quotes(`''`).

Comment: they were single quotes before and still are, still get that error message.